# Scala | Property File +HashMap or XML | What is better to use in refrence to performane of Scala program?

Tags: java, xml, scala, properties-file

I am new to Scala. I am making a TCP Server which reads from db for any number of registered client( By registered I mean Its entry shoul be in my property/XML file). So, I am confused among using XML config file or a property file+ HashMap. This a Sample code.

**XML**

```
<client-config>
        <clients>
                <client1 serviceId="1233" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.168.2.127:1521:mastera" username="sdp" password="sdp"/>
                <client2 serviceId="1234" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.168.2.127:1521:mastera" username="sdp" password="sdp"/>
        </clients>
</client-config>
```

**Loading/Reading**

```
val clientConfigXML = XML.loadFile("src/client_Config.xml")
if(clientConfigXML.toString.contains(serviceId)){
    val current_client = "client1"
    val dbURL = clientConfigXML \\"clients" \ current_client \ "@URL"
    val password = clientConfigXML \\"clients" \ current_client \ "@password"
    val username = clientConfigXML \\"clients" \ current_client \ "@username"
    val serviceId = clientConfigXML \\"clients" \ current_client \ "@serviceId"
    println("dbURL ["+dbURL+"] password ["+password+"] username ["+username+"] serviceId ["+serviceId +"]")
  }
```

I don't have any Idea how to detect client1/2/3...n while reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use label function

example

```
val xml = 
scala.xml.Utility.trim(<client-config>
  <clients>
    <client1 serviceId="1233" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.168.2.127:1521:mastera" username="sdp" password="sdp"/>
    <client2 serviceId="1234" URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.168.2.127:1521:mastera" username="sdp" password="sdp"/>
  </clients>
</client-config>)

val clientNames = ( xml \\ "clients").head.child.map(_.label)

/* clientNames is  'ArrayBuffer(client1, client2)' */
```